# What is the best approach or design pattern to call multiple microservices several times from a single service?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

Microservice A has dependency on Microservice B &C. When client calls a certain endpoint on service A, that will cause multiple HTTP requests to services B & C from A to get the dependent details. What would be the optimal, performance effective design pattern or approach to handle this scenario simultaneously?

NB : We are not using API gateway in this case.

Comment: You should generally try to develop microservices independently. If this is not possible, you could use a publish/subscribe mechanismn to notify the services about relevant events. This solves the _too many dependencies_ problem between microservices. If this is also not possible (you need to trigger businness logic), always consider asnc call to the remote service.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question I assume there is no ability to leverage the [event-based/reactive approach](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventCollaboration.html), and architectural decision is already made with tradeoffs as considered [here](https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/microservices-when-to-react-vs-orchestrate-c6b18308a14c) (note, in this source the approach proposed below is referenced as a 'Hybrid').

**Orchestration**

Under these conditions, the pattern you're looking for is called [**Orchestration**](http://soapatterns.org/compound_patterns/orchestration). Check out [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117570/orchestrating-microservices) for wider overview.

As a quick recap, you can use something like [Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/) to implement the following key points:

- While processing the request to A, execute calls to B & C concurrently where possible to achieve quickest response time from A
- Accumulate, transform and aggregate the results of concurrent calls into complete response entity
- Leverage thread pools to limit concurrently-running requests to B and C to prevent amplification of cascading failures
- Fail fast: early cancel the subsequent bunch of calls if some of requests fails (i.e. do not call C if call to B was not successful)
- Cut-off: involve the maximal processing time you can wait for completion of currently-running bunch of calls to B & C and respond with error by A upon elapsed

**Update - rely on implementation of [Reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) on client side**

If you can use Spring 5/Spring Boot 2.x, you can also make the calls to B & C in a reactive way using [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) based on [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs) to achieve above points.

Schematically, you can do something like:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    ...

    public Mono<Details> someRestCall(String name) {
        return this.webClient.get().url("{name}/details", name)
                        .retrieve().bodyToMono(ResponseEntity.class);
    }

}

...


Mono<ResponseEntity> b1 = myService.someRestCall("serviceB");
Mono<ResponseEntity> c1 = myService.someRestCall("serviceC");
Mono<ResponseEntity> b2 = myService.someOtherRestCall("serviceB");

ResponseEntity response = Flux
       .parallel(NUM_CPUS)
       .merge(b1, c1, b2)
       .limitRequest(MAX_REQUESTS)
       .onErrorReturn(ERR_RESPONSE_ENTITY)
       .blockLast(CUTOFF_TIMEOUT);
```

(based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203875/how-to-use-spring-webclient-to-make-multiple-calls-simultaneously))